# Two renderers in same adavanced data grid in Flash builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

i have a data grid which is having two renderers. one is text box and other is dropdwon. both are mxml rendered.

My requiremnet is when user edit the textbox value in a particular row i should make the dropdown value also changed of that particular row.

Could someone help me on this.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***If this is spark:***
The ItemRenderer has a property **owner** which is the dataGrid - you'll want to add an eventlistener on this (from the combobox one) - presumably coming from the other renderer which you dispatch from the owner point of view (eg: in textboxitemeditor: owner.dispatchEvent(RendererEvent.CHANGE, value))

In this listener - when the appropriate data was edited, you can update your combo box appropriately.

The key when doing something like this, is to remember to remove the listener and any other references you create in the *dispose()* method.

***If this is halo:***
It's essentially almost the same as above, the difference is there is a baseListData object which has the owner reference from the renderer.